# Modified Fibonacci in Java

Tags: java

A series is defined in the following manner:

Given the nth and (n+1)th terms, the (n+2)th can be computed by the following relation, 
Tn+2 = (Tn+1)2 + Tn
Given three integers A, B and N, such that the first two terms of the series (1st and 2nd terms) are A and B respectively, compute the Nth term of the series.

This is my code,

```
public static long fibonacciModified(int a, int b, int n){

        long[] arr = new long[n];
        arr[0] = a;
        arr[1] = b;
        for(int i = 2; i< n; i++){
          arr[i] = (long)(Math.pow(arr[i-1], 2) + arr[i-2]);  
        }
        return arr[n-1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(strArray[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(strArray[1]);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(strArray[2]);
        System.out.println(fibonacciModified(a, b, n));

    }
```

What could be the logical bug in this code, since it's not passing most of the test cases. I don't have access to the test cases. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific; is there an error message? What exactly is not working? Do you mean  Tn+2 = (Tn+1)^2 + Tn in the problem description?

Comment: I'd suggest producing your own test cases first. Also, if you have access to your program's output, you can trace which inputs you get.

Comment: for(int i = 2; i< n; i++){  in your main n = 2 and the end condition in the loop is i < n & i = 2:::: add  set condition to i <= n

Comment: Some people have no life but to down vote others on stack overflow. Disgusting.

Comment: There are no error messages, since the code is working, but the result is not in conformity with the provided test cases. Isn't that adequately clear in the question.

Comment: @CodelsLife that gives array out of bound exception since my array has only n elements.

Comment: @Zeus - You have been downvoted (not by me) because you are not giving us any way to help. What logical error are you observing? What inputs are you testing with and what result are you getting that is wrong?

Comment: Is it for a coding challenge? In that case you'd normally have at least access to some test cases which would allow you to verify whether your code produces the desired results.

Comment: @Thomas yes it's a coding  challenge and it passes the two provided test case, so the code is partially correct. The rest 8 cases it doesn't pass.

Comment: What happens if n is 0 or 1? Shouldn't you have different cases at start of your recursive method for this?

Comment: Just a side note but it might still help: you don't need an array since you're only interested in the last 3 values for each iteration. That would save memory and might help prevent not passing due to restrictions that might be imposed and huge values for `n`.

Comment: Another thing: since `Math.pow()` operates on doubles it might introduce precision or rounding errors. Why don't you just use `arr[i-1] * arr[i-1]` instead?

Comment: I just tested `Math.pow()` vs. integer math and it starts to differ for values greater than 94952467 on my machine and you'll reach that value quite fast, e.g. for a = 0, b = 1 and n = 7.

Comment: I've changed it to the multiplicand still dont pass the test cases.

Comment: Ok then I can think of 2 other issues: the first and more likely is you misunderstood the task and it's not (Tn+1)^2 but (Tn+1) * 2. The second would be that squaring would quickly lead to overflows since long can only hold values up to 9223372036854775807 but with the example above you'll end up with Tn+2 = 290287121823 which when squared exeeds that by far and in that case use `BigInteger` instead (ofc the return value would have to be able to represent that (and if you're required to return `long` I'd say the first issue is more likely).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get Nth Fibocanni number directly in O(1) here

```
System.out.println((1/Math.sqrt(5))*(Math.pow(((1+Math.sqrt(5))/2),3)-Math.pow(((1-Math.sqrt(5))/2),3)));
```

performance O(1)

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Use BigInteger as your test cases are unknown. Just using a static example here. Always cover all cases in code challenges such as n=1 or n=2 as you need to return a and b for those. Pass n-2 to method as given the first two elements your first run will calculate the third element, so overall you run it n-2 times. So when n is 0 we end recursion.

```
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int n = 4;
    BigInteger result;
    if (n == 1) {
        result = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
    } else if (n == 2) {
        result = BigInteger.valueOf(b);
    } else {
        result = fibonacciModified(BigInteger.valueOf(a), BigInteger.valueOf(b), n - 2);
    }
    System.out.println(result);


 public static BigInteger fibonacciModified(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return b;
        } else {
            return fibonacciModified(b, ((a.add(BigInteger.ONE)).pow(2)).add(b), n - 1);
        }
    }
```